# What is the need for Titan / JanusGraph management system?

Tags: graph, graph-databases, titan, janusgraph

I went through the JanusGraph and Titan documentation and it keeps calling other function like "makeEdgeLabel" etc. on the Management Object but I fail to understand the exact use of Management class because to my understanding I could call the same functions on the "JanusGraph" as well.

I would like to understand the exact meaning of the so called **"management system"** in JanusGraph.

Answer (score 5):

Both Titan and JanusGraph have the notion of a [schema](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/schema.html) which allows you to define what your graph looks like. This schema language on the "management object" is quite similar to a [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) in SQL. By telling Titan/JanusGraph what the schema for your data looks like, you give it hints on how to optimize storage and traversals.

Comment: To add to what Stephen has said it also allows you to create [indices](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html) which is essential for any large graph.